# How to avoid improper update of Dynamic in a Dialog?

Tags: dynamic, inputfield, dialog-window

I want to request user input of an expression of f(x) from a dialog and then use `ToExpression` on the input.

Questions:

1. When I execute the code below, I got r before I click the button. So that I  get r before I actually enter the expression. Is it because I'm using Dynamic[input]?
2. How to execute the last line after I hit the button?

```
x = Table[i, {i, 20}];
input = "";
CreateDialog[
  Grid[
    {{"f(x)=", InputField[Dynamic[input], String]},               
     {"", "Input expression f(x)"},
     {"", DefaultButton["OK", DialogReturn[ret = input]]}},
    Spacings -> {0.5, Automatic}, 
    Alignment -> Center
  ],
  Modal -> True, 
  WindowTitle -> "Input information"];
r = ToExpression[ret, TraditionalForm];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you define `x` and then never use it but despite that try this:

```
ret = DialogInput[
   DialogNotebook[{
     DynamicModule[{input},
      Grid[{{"f(x)=", InputField[Dynamic[input], String]}, {"", 
         "Input expression f(x)"}, {"", 
         DefaultButton["OK", DialogReturn[input]]}}, 
       Spacings -> {0.5, Automatic}, Alignment -> Center]
      ]
     }],
   ShowStringCharacters -> False,
   WindowTitle -> "Input information"];
```

Comment: Hi Mike, sorry about the confusion. I was trying to use the input expression to manipulate vector x. Your answer solved my question perfectly. Thank you very much!